# Python making the target of a Thread be a property setter

Tags: python, properties, python-multithreading, callable-object

I have a class with:

- A private instance attribute
- Used `property` decorator to make a getter and a setter for the attribute

How can I make the setter be the target callable object of a `threading.Thread`?

The problem seems to be that the setter is not Callable.  Is there a good workaround for this?

---

**Sample Code**

My current workaround is to make the setter without using the `property` decorator.

However, I would really like to not add a second setter.  Is there a better way?

```py
from threading import Thread


class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._some_attr = 0

    @property
    def some_attr(self) -> int:
        return self._some_attr

    @some_attr.setter
    def some_attr(self, val: int):
        self._some_attr = val

    def set_some_attr(self, val: int):
        self._some_attr = val


some_class = SomeClass()

my_thread = Thread(target=SomeClass.set_some_attr, args=(some_class, 1))  # This works fine
my_thread.start()
my_thread.join()
print(some_class.some_attr)

my_thread2 = Thread(target=SomeClass.some_attr, args=  # How is this done?
my_thread2.start()
my_thread2.join()
print(some_class.some_attr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SomeClass.some_attr` returns a `property` object, which is indeed not callable. This property object has two attributes useful to you - the `fget` and `fset` attributes, which hold the getter and setter functions for that property. `fget` always points to a function, while `fset` might be `None` if no setter is defined.

An example for using the setter in a separate thread:

```py
my_thread2 = Thread(target=SomeClass.some_attr.fset, args=(some_class, 1))
my_thread2.start()
my_thread2.join()
print(some_class.some_attr)
```

Answer (score 2):

kmaork's answer works, but you could also just use `setattr`:

```
thread = Thread(target=setattr, args=(obj, 'attrname', value))
```

This avoids relying on any implementation details of how the attribute is implemented. You don't need to make the setter the target; you just need to make the target set the attribute.